# update list from another list using ECMA/client object model?

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-enterprise, javascript, client-object-model, rest

I have eleven lists list1,list2,..list10.and listDup Now i want to update ListDup's SID column based on List1's SID . when the time of adding item in List1(List2,List3,..List10) i have to check sid whether it is existing or not in ListDup . If it is there in ListDup, It wont allow us to save in List1(List2,...List10).
SID is sitecolumn.

I have tried designer workflow but it is s bit lazy update. 
i have no chance to use event receivers. suggest me if you have any idea to do this by ecma/rest/...

Answer (score 1):

You could do that by implementing a jsLink validation for the field. Use the basic jsLink approach to render the default form and apply another validation function to check the other list.

Here's a basic approach for that:

```
//check if we need jsLink
if (window.SPClientTemplates) {
    (function (_) {
        'use strict';

        function renderTextField(ctx, defaultRender) {
            //get the form context - it contains a lot of useful stuff and there are some events we need to define to ensure everything is working
            var formCtx = SPClientTemplates.Utility.GetFormContextForCurrentField(ctx);

            //build Custom ValidatorSet
            var customValidator = function () {
                customValidator.prototype.Validate = function (value) {
                    var isError = false;
                    var errorMessage = '';

                    //do some synchronous jsom to check whatever you want (check this http://www.sharepointnadeem.com/2014/10/sharepoint-using-deferredspromises-or.html)

                    if (value.indexOf('A') === -1) {
                        isError = true;
                        errorMessage = 'The Value must contain an "A".';
                    }
                    return new SPClientForms.ClientValidation.ValidationResult(isError, errorMessage);
                };
            };

            //set validator
            var validators = new SPClientForms.ClientValidation.ValidatorSet();
            validators.RegisterValidator(new customValidator());
            formCtx.registerClientValidator(formCtx.fieldName, validators);

            //get default HTML/Events
            var defaultHtml = defaultRender(ctx);
            return defaultHtml;
        }

        function register() {
            var jsLink = {
                Templates: {
                    Fields: {}
                }
            };

            jsLink.Templates.Fields['Text'] = { //use your internal fieldname here or all fields of type "Text" are modified
                //'View': function(ctx){ return RenderFieldValueDefault(ctx);},
                //'DisplayForm': function(ctx) { return SPField_FormDisplay_Default(ctx)},
                'EditForm': function (ctx) { return renderTextField(ctx, SPFieldText_Edit); },
                'NewForm': function (ctx) { return renderTextField(ctx, SPFieldText_Edit); }
            };


            SPClientTemplates.TemplateManager.RegisterTemplateOverrides(jsLink);
        }
        ExecuteOrDelayUntilScriptLoaded(register, 'clienttemplates.js');
    })({});
}
```

Comment: Remember that all clientside validation does not really prevent false input (even the buildin ones like required, etc.) it's not forbidden to set the value over code. If you want a REAL prevention of listelements with certain data you will most likely need SSOM.